# How to properly authenticate user against Active Directory?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, active-directory, owin

I'm trying to authenticate users against Active Directory and I'm using the code below to validate their credentials.

```
bool isValid = principalContext.ValidateCredentials(username, password, ContextOptions.Negotiate);

if (isValid)
{
    userPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalContext, username);
}
```

My problem is that the ValidateCredentials method doesn't validate the user's password when `username = "domain\username"` and always returns true, but when the `username = "username"` or `username@domain.com`, it works and return false when the password is invalid.

**Scenario 1:**

username = "CorrectUserName" and password = "IncorrectPassword" => isValid = false.

username = "CorrectUserName" and password = "CorrectPassword" => isValid = true.

**Scenario 2:**

username = "CorrectUserName@Domain.com" and password = "IncorrectPassword" => isValid = false.

username = "CorrectUserName@Domain.com" and password = "CorrectPassword" => isValid = true.

**Scenario 3 (this is my problem):**

username = "Domain\CorrectUserName" and password = "IncorrectPassword" => isValid = true.

username = "Domain\CorrectUserName" and password = "CorrectPassword" => isValid = true.

My code looks like this [tutorial](https://tech.trailmax.info/2016/03/using-owin-and-active-directory-to-authenticate-users-in-asp-net-mvc-5-application/) with minor changes.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: When you initialize the PrincipalContext, you should be defining the domain.  When you pass the username to the validate method, it does *not* want a domain pre- or app-ended.

Comment: I can't replicate your problem. Specifying username prefixed with domain as in your Scenario 3, I get `false` for correct and incorrect passwords as I'd expect.

Comment: @itsme86 i tried to replicate my problem with two of my co-workers and it returns true for incorrect passwords. but in [ValidateCredentials docs](https://scontent.ftun1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/42324994_2528574920493221_1616801371556675584_n.jpg?_nc_cat=103&oh=9c6e03cb67f6ccaee5f8dc169bf07334&oe=5C225AB1) in remaks section that the userName argument must take the form username (for example, mcampbell) rather than domain\username or username@domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ValidateCredentials` takes a username without domain information.  The domain should be defined when creating the `PrincipalContext`:

```
if (!username.Contains("@") && !username.Contains(@"\"))
{
    // EXCEPTION
}

var domain = username.Contains("@") ? username.Split("@")[1].Split(".")[0] : username.Split(@"\")[0];
var principalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain);

var user = username.Contains("@") ? username.Split("@")[0] : username.Split(@"\")[1];
var isValid = principalContext.ValidateCredentials(user, cleartextpw);
```

---

### [`PrincipalContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.principalcontext?view=netframework-4.7.2)

### [`ValidateCredentials`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.principalcontext.validatecredentials?view=netframework-4.7.2)